# What is the correct way to read decimal numbers?

Tags: numbers

If the number is 100.32, which option is correct?

1. One hundred point thirty-two.
2. One hundred point three two.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] and do some research before posting. An English language site on basic mathematics will explain the logic behind the standard English language usage. If, as I suspect, you are not a native English speaker, you might look on English Language Learners, where I imagine this will have already been asked.

Comment: (1) is incorrect, because "thirty-two" means 3 tens and 2 units, whereas the fractional part here is 3 tenths and 2 hundredths. It also doesn't distinguish from `100.032`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I disagree. "One-hundred point thirty-two" is quite natural to me for 100.32. OTOH, 100.032 would be said "One hundred point zero three two" or "One hundred point zero thirty-two". (For enunciation into a noisy channel, I would say "one zero zero point zero three two.)

Comment: https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/02/decimal-point.html
i read this article, thats why i don't know what is correct option

Comment: The blog starts with "When you’re speaking or writing numbers, the word “and” is actually the decimal point. So one hundred thirty-two is 132, but one hundred and thirty-two is 100.32". That's complete nonsense: "One hundred and thirty-two" and "One hundred thirty-two" both mean 132.

Comment: @Weather Vane: To be fair, that's a _question_, which the blogger corrects in the very next paragraph.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian yes, it goes on to say what I wrote. I didn't read far enough.

Comment: @bloomer_xx: At that grammarphobia link, **Q** means it's a question. The answer, marked **A**, tells the questioner, "This is a common misconception, but in spoken or written numbers the conjunction “and” does not mean decimal point. " Weather Vane has explained that "thirty-two" means 3 tens and 2 units. For 100.32 we say "one hundred point three two".

Comment: Interestingly, when I was in elementary school we were taught to never say “and” in the whole number part: “one hundred thirty two not one hundred and thirty two.” And to use the and only as the decimal point ***but then*** one had to also specify the fraction: One hundred thirty two and twenty nine hundredths.   Of course nobody does this- me included.   So as @WeatherVane says: one hundred and thirty two = 132.  But one hundred and thirty two hundredths = 100.32 And if you’re a machinist it’d be one hundred and three hundred and twenty thousandths.